# In C#, do you need to call the base constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

In C#, if I have an inherited class with a default constructor, do I have to explicitly call the base class' constructor or will it be implicitly called?

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        // ... some code
    }
}
class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public MyClass() // Do I need to put ": base()" here or is it implied?
    {
        // ... some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly call the base constructor, it will be implicitly called.

Extend your example a little and create a Console Application and you can verify this behaviour for yourself:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass foo = new MyClass();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseClass constructor called.");
        }
    }

    class MyClass : BaseClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass constructor called.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the base constructor has arguments, then would it still be automatically called?

Comment: no, the base constructor is only called for parameterless constructors

Answer (score 32):

It is implied, provided it is parameterless. This is because you **need to implement constructors that take values**, see the code below for an example:

```
public class SuperClassEmptyCtor
{
    public SuperClassEmptyCtor()
    {
        // Default Ctor
    }
}

public class SubClassA : SuperClassEmptyCtor
{
    // No Ctor's this is fine since we have
    // a default (empty ctor in the base)
}

public class SuperClassCtor
{
    public SuperClassCtor(string value)
    {
        // Default Ctor
    }
}

public class SubClassB : SuperClassCtor
{
    // This fails because we need to satisfy
    // the ctor for the base class.
}

public class SubClassC : SuperClassCtor
{
    public SubClassC(string value) : base(value)
    {
        // make it easy and pipe the params
        // straight to the base!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It's implied for base parameterless constructors, but it is needed for defaults in the current class:

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected string X;

    public BaseClass() {
        this.X = "Foo";
    }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public MyClass() 
        // no ref to base needed
    {
        // initialise stuff
        this.X = "bar";
    }

    public MyClass(int param1, string param2)
        :this() // This is needed to hit the parameterless ..ctor
    {
         // this.X will be "bar"
    }

    public MyClass(string param1, int param2)
        // :base() // can be implied
    {
         // this.X will be "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit old to be sure, but in case anyone stumbles across this. Note that in your overloaded constructor the call order will actually be: base() -> MyClass() -> MyClass(int param1, string param2). Your comment next to "this()" seemed somewhat misleading as if adding the this() would  prevent the call to instantiate the base class.

Comment: @Wrightboy yes, that is the correct order in which the constructors will get called. My point was just that it isn't implied - you can explicitly specify `this()` or `base()`, but if you don't then neither will get called.

Comment: `base()` is always called. `public MyClass(int param1, string param2)` and `public MyClass(int param1, string param2) : base()` are equivalent. The `this()` just adds in additional call after the `base()` call but before itself.

Comment: There is no "base" class here. This is just constructor chaining. Has little to do with the question.

Comment: @iheanyi could you expand?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment, not realizing you'd see it this quickly. This is just an example of constructor chaining. There is no base class constructor being called - because there is no inheritance.

Comment: And, it's wrong to say if :this() was not present, there would be a call to :base(). There is no :base() to call, unless we're talking Object()

Comment: @iheanyi sorry, I thought there being a base class could be taken as read, given the context of the question. I've expanded the example to explicitly reference a base class in order to make this clear.

Comment: Wait. . .were you perhaps just expanding on part of the code in the question? If so, then I misunderstood your answer. Haha, again, our comments cross while writing.

Comment: @iheanyi yeah, rather than include all the code already in the question I just expanded on the constructors to try and make a specific point. I've expanded to make it less confusing if taken out of that context.

Answer (score 7):

It is implied.

Comment: This is correct, because the OP stated "default (aka parameterless) constructor".

Answer (score 5):

A derived class is built upon the base class. If you think about it, the base object has to be instantiated in memory before the derived class can be appended to it. So the base object will be created on the way to creating the derived object. So no, you do not call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you only need to call the base constructor if you need to pass down any values to it.

Answer (score -3):

You don’t need call the base constructor explicitly it will be implicitly called, but sometimes you need pass parameters to the constructor in that case you can do something like:

```
using System;
namespace StackOverflow.Examples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NewClass foo = new NewClass("parameter1","parameter2");
            Console.WriteLine(foo.GetUpperParameter());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    interface IClass
    {
        string GetUpperParameter();
    }

    class BaseClass : IClass
    {
        private string parameter;
        public BaseClass (string someParameter)
        {
            this.parameter = someParameter;
        }

        public string GetUpperParameter()
        {
            return this.parameter.ToUpper();
        }
    }

    class NewClass : IClass
    {
        private BaseClass internalClass;
        private string newParameter;

        public NewClass (string someParameter, string newParameter)
        {
            this.internalClass = new BaseClass(someParameter);
            this.newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        public string GetUpperParameter()
        {
            return this.internalClass.GetUpperParameter() + this.newParameter.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If someone knows a better solution please tells me.

Comment: Looks like somebody needs a lesson in composition vs inheritance.  ;)